# Pre-compile-time decision based on macro-parameter

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I got this macro that posts events to some event-queue.

```
POST_(myTarget, event)
```

The event may either be posted directly to a local queue or may be serialized and posted to the event-queue of a I2C service which sends the event to another microcontroller. Whether the receiving service is local or remote is defined like:

```
#define myTarget_REMOTE
#define anotherTarget_LOCAL
```

What I want to do is something like this (which is certainly not allowed):

```
#define POST(target, e) \
    #ifdef target##_REMOTE \
        /* create a i2c request-event with serialized(e) 
           as parameter and post to I2c-Manager */
    #else \
        /* post directly */
        POST_(target, event) \
    #endif
```

So, all the information is there at compile time, but I don't know how to tell the preprocessor what to do.

- I could create two macros for each target depending on its local/remote define, but this would be messy.
- I could do the test at runtime, but this would be a sad story also.

EDIT:

An example how the program will look like  clearer:

```
#define target1_LOCAL
#define target2_REMOTE

POST(target1, e) ==preprocessor==> POST_(target1, e)

POST(target2, e) ==preprocessor==> 
    do { \
        req = createI2cRequest(serialize(e)); \
        POST_(I2cManager, req); \
    }while(0)
```

So, in the program I just use `POST(target, event)` and the location of the target is completely transparent.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this (unsuccessfully) with a macro ?

Comment: this done quite often and i think it should be possible anyhow cause all information is present at compile time.

Comment: No - it's not going to work - you can't have conditional compilation within a macro definition (or rather you can, but it doesn't do what you want it to)

Comment: For the sake of precision, you can't do anything at compile time using macros, for the simple reason that the compile is fed with already precompiled files :p

Comment: Geoffrey, im sorry :)
@paul i know that it doesnt work this way, i only wanted to express what i want to achieve and i think it should be possible with some preprocessor magic. but im far from being a preprocessor magician.

Comment: @Dill: it definitely isn't going to work, even with boundless "preprocessor magic". It's 2012, not 1982 - time to stop abusing the preprocessor and write code properly. I take it your compiler supports C99, or at least inline functions ?

Comment: You should *at least* remove the semicolon after the funky `do { ...} while(0)` macro.

Comment: @wildplasser what else can i do to make you happy?

Comment: @PaulR after reading this (and Geoffreys comment) again this morning, i did some thinking at last and figured it out... thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally figured it out.
The trick is to use the preprocessor to give the compiler all needed information and rely on the compiler to optimize the if/else away.

```
#define REMOTE  1
#define LOCAL   0

#define TARGET0_LOCATION REMOTE
#define TARGET1_LOCATION LOCAL

#define TEST(target) do { \
        if(target##_LOCATION == REMOTE) printf("REMOTE\n"); \
        else printf("LOCAL\n"); \
    }while(0)

main(){
    TEST(TARGET0);
    TEST(TARGET1);
}
```

Output:

```
REMOTE
LOCAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional programming inside macros is a bit tricky, but doable with C99. In [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) I have programmed a family of conditionals that could be helpfull here.

```
#define myTarget_TYPE 0
#define anotherTarget_TYPE 1

#define POST(target, e)                                   \
    P99_IF_EQ_1(P99_PASTE2(target, _TYPE))                \
      (                                                   \
        /* create a i2c request-event with serialized(e)  \
           as parameter and post to I2c-Manager */        \
      )(                                                  \
        /* post directly */                               \
        POST_(target, event)                              \
      )
```

The trick is that you should always have the one macro per target. For those that you want the first alternative you have it to the token `1`. You could even omit to declare the others be to `0`.

The general form is something like

```
P99_IF_COND( /* expression(s) for condition */ )(/* case true */)(/* case false*/)
```

there are a lot of things that you can do with `COND` above, testing for equality to a specific token, equality of decimal numbers, emptyness of a parameter list...

Comment: thanks for this, unfortunately my compiler (IAR for ARM Cortex) does complain in p99_block.h, line 472 "noreturn",: Error: expected a string literal.

Comment: @Dill, ah this compiler I don't know. There are probably some switches to adjust. You could try to just put a `-Dnoreturn` on the compiler comand line for a start. I would be happy to look into this but I will be traveling the next days.

Comment: @Dill, could you please send me a more precise bug report offline? It would be nice to have something equivalent to `gcc` option `-dM`, something like `gcc -E -dM ./p99.h` to know all macros that your preprocessor provides.

Comment: im on vacation till october, then ill do that.

Answer (score 0):

Pull some definitions up like:-

```
#ifdef I2C
#define TARGETFUNC _REMOTE
#else
#define TARGETFUNC _LOCAL
#endif
#define POST(target, e) POST(target##TARGETFUNC,e)
```

Comment: i dont get this one. i edit the original post to be more clear what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define post_myTarget(x)       remote_post(x)
#define post_anotherTarget(x)  local_post(x)

#define POST(target, e) post_##target(e)
```

Comment: this needs a #define for each target. if this is the only way ill do a check at runtime and choose a stable and maintainable program over speed.